# Making a Pong ball reflect off the paddle

Tags: c++, game, sdl

I am currently making Pong in C++/SDL2 and after a while of tinkering, I have come up with a solution!

This function gets the hit position and returns the necessary direction change:

```
MoveDirection Ball::getHitPos(const Player& player) const
{
    MoveDirection dir; //Direction of movement

    //If ball is moving left
    if (m_dir == MoveDirection::LEFT)
    {   
        std::cout << "Yes";
        int hitPos = m_pos.y - player.getPos().y; //Get hit position
        int playerSize = player.getPos().h / 2; 
        int offSet = 25; //Enables to split up positions into three seperate parts
        //Calculate dir change
        if (hitPos <= playerSize - offSet) {
            dir = MoveDirection::RIGHTUP;
        }
        else if (hitPos >= playerSize + offSet) {
            dir = MoveDirection::RIGHTDOWN;
        }
        else {
            dir = MoveDirection::RIGHT;
        }
    }

    //If Ball is moving right
    if (m_dir == MoveDirection::RIGHT)
    {
        int hitPos = m_pos.y - player.getPos().y; //Get hit position
        int playerSize = player.getPos().h / 2;
        int offSet = 25; //Enables to split up positions into three seperate parts
        //Calculate dir change
        if (hitPos <= playerSize - offSet) {
            dir = MoveDirection::LEFTUP;
        }
        else if (hitPos >= playerSize + offSet) {
            dir = MoveDirection::LEFTDOWN;
        }
        else {
            dir = MoveDirection::LEFT;
        }
    }

    return dir;
}
```

Here are all of the possible movement directions:

```
enum class MoveDirection
{
    UP,
    DOWN,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT,
    LEFTUP, //Ball diagonal movement
    LEFTDOWN, //Ball diagonal movement
    RIGHTUP, //Ball diagonal movement
    RIGHTDOWN //Ball diagonal movement
};
```

And here is the height of the racket:

```
static constexpr int SIZE_HEIGHT = 75;
```

I must also note that `m_pos` is `SDL_RECT` and `player.getPos().y` is getting the `y` element of `SDL_RECT`.

Comment: Is this real code?  The function calculates `dir` and then discard the result.

Comment: Oh! Oops, sorry that was there for test purposes on the actual function its self. Sorry! I thought I uploaded the working one, my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ball can only move in the eight (semi)cardinal directions? It can't move at, say, a 30-degree angle?

Well, even so, it will simplify your code to treat the ball as if it *can* move in any direction. Either:

```
struct MoveDirection {
    double angle;
    double speed;
};
```

or more likely:

```
struct MoveDirection {
    double vx;
    double vy;
};
```

And then rewrite your `getHitPos` function as something more like

```
MoveDirection Ball::getHitPos(const Player& player) const
{
    MoveDirection dir; //Direction of movement

    //If ball is moving left
    if (m_dir.vx < 0)
    {   
        std::cout << "Yes";
        int hitPos = m_pos.y - player.getPos().y; //Get hit position
        int playerSize = player.getPos().h / 2; 
        int offSet = 25; //Enables to split up positions into three seperate parts
        //Calculate dir change
        dir.vx = +1;
        if (hitPos <= playerSize - offSet) {
            dir.vy = +1;
        }
        else if (hitPos >= playerSize + offSet) {
            dir.vy = -1;
        }
        else {
            dir.vy = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (m_dir.vx > 0)  // ball is moving right
...
```

Then just keep refactoring and turning branches into arithmetic expressions until you're happy. It might end up looking something like

```
MoveDirection result;
result.vx = -m_dir.vx;
const double hitPos = m_pos.y - player.getPos().y; //Get hit position
const double playerSize = player.getPos().h / 2;
result.vy = (hitPos > playerSize + 25) - (hitPos < playerSize - 25);
return result;
```

Answer (score 3):

I see a few things that may help you improve your code.

### Think carefully about object responsibilities

It seems peculiar to me that `Ball` is responsible for determining where on the `Player` it has hit.  I'd suggest refactoring so that yo have the paddle divided into regions and have a `Player` member enum class and function like this:

```
enum class PaddleRegion { LOW, MID, HI};
PaddleRegion getPaddleHitRegion(int y_pos) const;
```

### Make your class more data-centric

The resulting direction is a function of the original direction of the ball and the region in which it hit.  None of these is dynamic.  That is, given a direction and region, the output will always be the same.  This suggests that perhaps the `Ball` class could instead incorporate a `static` table like this:

```
class Ball {
    // other stuff... 
    struct Rebound {
        MoveDirection incomingDir;
        Player::PaddleRegion region;
        MoveDirection outgoingDir;
    };
    const static Rebound bounce[]; 
};
```

It could then be populated like this:

```
const Ball::Rebound Ball::bounce[] 
{
    {MoveDirection::LEFT, Player::PaddleRegion::LOW, MoveDirection::RIGHTDOWN}, 
    {MoveDirection::LEFT, Player::PaddleRegion::MID, MoveDirection::RIGHT}, 
    {MoveDirection::LEFT, Player::PaddleRegion::HI, MoveDirection::RIGHTUP}, 
    {MoveDirection::RIGHT, Player::PaddleRegion::LOW, MoveDirection::LEFTDOWN}, 
    {MoveDirection::RIGHT, Player::PaddleRegion::MID, MoveDirection::LEFT}, 
    {MoveDirection::RIGHT, Player::PaddleRegion::HI, MoveDirection::LEFTUP}, 
};
```

Now the code for `Ball::getHitPos()` looks like this:

```
MoveDirection Ball::getHitPos(const Player& player) const {
    Player::PaddleRegion region = player.getPaddleHitRegion(m_pos.y);
    for (const auto &b : bounce) {
        if (b.incomingDir == m_dir && b.region == region) {
            return b.outgoingDir;
        }
    }
    // not found, so pick an arbitrary direction
    return MoveDirection::RIGHT;
}
```

The advantages are many.  First, it's easy to add additional incoming ball directions.  Second, all of the interactions are captured in a single compact table so it's easy to review and change.